# How can I run some code in Node prior to running a browser test with Intern?

Tags: intern

With Intern, how can I run some setup code in Node prior to running browser tests, but *not* when running Node tests? I know that I could do that outside of Intern completely, but is there anything that's a part of Intern that could handle that?

For a more concrete example: I'm running tests for an HTTP library that communicates with a Python server. When running in Node, I can run `spawn("python", ["app.py"])` to start the server. However, in the browser, I would need to run that command before the browser begins running the tests.

Phrased another way: is there a built-in way with Intern to run some code in the Node process prior to launching the browser tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Intern will run the plugins configured for `node` regardless of which environment you're running in.

So, you could create a plugin that hooks into the `runStart` and `runEnd` events like this:

```js
intern.on("runStart", () => {
  console.log("Starting...");
  // Setup code here
});

intern.on("runEnd", () => {
  console.log("Ending...");
  // Teardown code here
});
```

These handlers will run inside the Node process, and thus have access to all the available Node APIs.

Additionally, you can detect which environments are being tested by looking at `intern.config.environments`:

```js
{
  environments: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      browserVersion: undefined,
      version: undefined
    }
  ]
}
```

By looking at the environments, you can determine whether or not you need to run your setup code.